# Load Data Grid View dynamically using c# on scroll in Win form application

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I would like to know how could we implement a `DataGridView` (Win form Control) fill on scroll dynamically, I have a 10000+ records, and I would like to show 100 item first and I would like to load dynamically on scroll.

Thanks for answer in advance.

Comment: [Virtual mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.virtualmode(v=vs.110).aspx) of `DataGridView` is designed for use with very large stores of data.  Take a look at [Implementing Virtual Mode with Just-In-Time Data Loading in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171624(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you @RezaAghaei, I will have a look on the same

Comment: You mean "Paging"? That is the keyword you want to Google.